# Apache Beam - how to trigger empty windows?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to do a simple running count in Apache Beam (Dataflowrunner), but have a difficult time finding a suitable solution.

The goal of the pipeline:

- Pubsub input: events
- Pubsub output: every 30 seconds, number of events seen in the past 5 minutes

Problem:

> whenever there is an empty window, I want to see 0 as the count. This does not happen.

**Attempt 1: Count globally**

Yields an error that I need to use:

```
Combine.globally(Count.<T>combineFn()).withoutDefaults()
```

```
PCollection slidingCount =
     input.apply("Create Windows",
         Window.into(
             SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(300))
             .every(Duration.standardSeconds(30)))
          )
          .apply("Count elements in window",
             Count.globally()
          );
```

**Attempt 2: Combiner**

Yields an error that I need to provide `withoutdefaults()` option.

```
PCollection slidingCount =
     input.apply("Create Windows",
         Window.into(
             SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(300))
             .every(Duration.standardSeconds(30)))
          )
          .apply("Count elements in window",
              Combine.globally(Count.<PubsubMessage>combineFn())
          );
```

**Attempt 3: withoutdefaults**

This does not generate empty windows. By definition of course.

```
PCollection slidingCount =
     input.apply("Create Windows",
         Window.into(
             SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(300))
             .every(Duration.standardSeconds(30)))
          )
          .apply("Count elements in window",
              Combine.globally(Count.<PubsubMessage>combineFn())
              .withoutDefaults()
          );
```

**Attempt 4: asSingletonView**

Adding this option turns my collection into a view, which I cannot reuse to continue my pipeline.

```
PCollectionView slidingCount =
     input.apply("Create Windows",
         Window.into(
             SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(300))
             .every(Duration.standardSeconds(30)))
          )
          .apply("Count elements in window",
              Combine.globally(Count.<PubsubMessage>combineFn())
              .asSingletonView()
          );
```

Any suggestions on how I can approach this.

Comment: One possible way is you can convert your PCollection to PCollection<K, V> where K is a dummy key (can easy to do this conversion by WithKeys transform in Beam), and then you can does a Count.perKey to workaround Combine.globally limitation. However, I am not sure if Count.perKey assigns default value to empty window. I don't have tools to verify it now.

Comment: And I guess Beam does not support it because window is also a grouping key. When you do a grouping, how can we know a non-existing key? Making assumption or relying on state backend is too much for a programming model.

Answer (score 2):

You can use timers and state with a global window if you need to emit a result in every 30 seconds even if there was no event since the last firing. I think it is not possible to do it with the built in triggers and windows.

You can keep the count of every half minute in a state and use a timer to emit the results periodically and drop the unnecessary counts. These two blog post explains the usage of timers and state:

[Stateful processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html)

[Timely (and Stateful) Processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html)