# How to handle lack of messages from Pub/Sub in Google Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

The below is just random example code:

```
import argparse
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.transforms import window
from apache_beam.transforms.trigger import AfterWatermark, AccumulationMode

class FormatDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, viewing, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
        print(viewing)

def main(argv=None):

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    with beam.Pipeline(argv=pipeline_args) as p:

        # Read from PubSub messages.
        input = p | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub("projects/example-project/topics/example")

        transformed = (
            input
            | beam.WindowInto(
                                window.FixedWindows(5),
                                trigger = AfterWatermark(),
                                accumulation_mode = AccumulationMode.DISCARDING
                            )

            | 'Format' >> beam.ParDo(FormatDoFn())
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have a working Dataflow job that processes Pub/Sub messages per fixed window interval and inserts the aggregated results to a table. However, it only makes inserts when messages are received.

How can I make the dataflow job insert a Zero Value row once a window has passed without any messages received.

Comment: Hi @Shahid Thaika, can you clarify where your destination table was created and also provide a sample code that you have tried?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar I am writing to BQ, but haven't tried anything for what I need, as I don't know where to start. The input step only gets elements if there is a message received from PubSub. I want it to populate some data when no messages are received.

Comment: I have not yet worked much with Windows in beam, so I don't know if there is any out-of-the-box solutions for this. However, I think you could maybe use [timers](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#timers) in your `FormatDoFn`? Basically fire it after X seconds, regardless of the step above produces input to this DoFn.

Comment: To second @CaptainNabla, I also think timers/state would be the best solution here. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444718/apache-beam-how-to-trigger-empty-windows, as it points to useful resources.

Comment: Hi @ShahidThaika, did the above comment help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be very simple for my use case. I just generated dummy KVs and combined it with the regular Pubsub message transformed KVs.

```
PCollection<Long> input = pipeline
                            .apply("unbounded longs",
                                    GenerateSequence
                                            .from(0)
                                            .withRate(2, Duration.standardSeconds(1))
                            );
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @CaptainNabla and  @Bruno Volpato , you can use [timers](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#timers) which will allow delayed processing. You can keep the count of every half minute in a state and use a timer to emit the results periodically and drop the unnecessary counts. The [timer](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/state/Timer.html#:%7E:text=A%20timer%20exists%20in%20one,requested%20time%2C%20in%20timestamp%20order.) can be set or unset. For more information, you can use Timely and Stateful processing. For more information, you can check this [link](https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/).